# IntelliJ highlights as error a working code in Griffon

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, griffon

Below is a snippet from a working code taken from the Groovy in Action book.
As you see below, IntelliJ sees it as error.

Why?

See picture below:

[image]

Comment: I've known IntelliJ's support with Groovy/Griffon to be shaky.  Double check on their [bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) that there's not an open bug for this already, and if there *is*, report your findings, too.

Comment: New ticket was created [IDEA-105357](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-105357).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think IDEA is to blame here. Griffon is exploiting a trick that Groovy brings to the table: using closures as annotation values. However @PropertyListener goes a bit further by allowing closure properties to be used too, but in order to do it converts invalid code (a property name cannot be used as an annotation value) into valid code (changes the annotation value into an empty String).

There is no way IDEA can be aware that the Griffon compiler is using this trick, hence the red squiggles. Regardless of this, don't be alarmed, the Griffon compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: So, it's next task for IntelliJ to handle such sort of tricks :)

Comment: Only if a ticket is raised in their issue tracker and a patch is submitted. Griffon support for IDEA is provided by the Community Edition, which means anyone can read the code and submit a patch.

Comment: The ticket (I mentioned above) was created just today by JetBrains. Its subject: Griffon: @PropertyListener annotation

Comment: Added a bit more of information to IDEA-105357 so that implementors know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable input on the ticket!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.2 will support it